# Leftover parts after head gasket change; are they engine mounts or braces?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, part-identification, shaking

About a year ago, I replaced a head gasket on a 1994 Chevy Cavalier 2.2L. After I put everything back together there were two parts left over. The car runs good considering it's 20 years old, however I'm assuming these were bracing parts; when the car gets above about 55mph or so, it shakes.

It does the same when you rev the car in neutral, so it's nothing to do with the tires, and they were all replaced recently anyways.

The car shakes when it's cold, before it warms up, or if its been sitting awhile, so I suspect it's these two parts. It also loses speed quicker than before.

I'm not sure where it is that they go exactly. My assumption is on the passenger side within the engine bay.

Here are two pics of the parts.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can't upload images bigger than 2MB, for future reference.

Comment: Some hints for people answering the question: the 2.2 is the four cylinder engine and the pictures appear to be on the lid of a washing machine (to give a sense of scale).

Comment: yes they are. the rod piece with the flattened ends is roughly 8 inches. and the other piece is about a foot from end to end. and its a manual trans.

Comment: What are the measurements of the washing machine?

Comment: I think the top picture is the backside mount for the power steering pump and the second goes from that bracket to the manifold.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Civic. It was actually an intake mount, one little bracket causing all the shaking. I just decided to let the motor rest on it and didn't bolt it back together until later. I bent mine pushing and shoving up and down on the intake getting it out. Apparently motors and how they are mounted are very balanced pieces of machinery. But it's easy to fix. Just get the brackets back on and it'll go away. Not sure what you're working on but it's probably a combination of a part of the motor hanging outward, giving just enough vibration and leverage to shake the car.

Answer (score 1):

Is the top one plastic.  It kinda looks like a splash shield.  It might go around the cv axle.  I can think of two places the tubular brace might go.  One is on the alternator to the engine.  The other is from the engine to the transaxle underneath the car.

I highly doubt either of these is causing your vibration unless something has cracked due to a lack of support.